# sails.js many to many query

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to build a chat app. I have a many-to-many association. A room have many users. And a user can have many rooms. I am trying to retrieve the room which has both user A (fromUserId) and user B (toUserId). I am trying something like this but I know it's not correct:

```
Room.find().populate('users', { where:{ id: [fromUserId, toUserId] } }).exec(function(err, rooms){
  console.log(rooms);
});
```

The problem here is that it returns any rooms that users.id = fromUserId **or** toUserId. What I need here is an **and** query.

Any help appreciated. (:

Comment: which database you're using?

Comment: Ryan Wu mongodb with waterline ORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Mongodb with waterline, you can use $in

```
Room.native(function(err, collection) {
collection.find({
    "users" : {
      $in : [fromUserId, toUserId]
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) return res.badRequest(err);
    console.dir(results)
  });
});
```

the disadvantage is that its native mongodb feature, you can't use that in other database.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be hard-pressed to do this even with raw SQL.  Your best bet is to get all the rooms that each user is in, and then get the intersection:

```
// Get the fromUser and their rooms
User.findOne(fromUserId).populate('rooms').exec(function(err, fromUser) {
  // Get the toUser and their rooms
  User.findOne(toUserId).populate('rooms').exec(function(err, toUser) {
    // Get the IDs of the rooms they are both in
    var fromUserRoomIds = _.pluck(fromUser.rooms, 'id');
    var toUserRoomIds = _.pluck(toUser.rooms, 'id');
    var sharedRoomIds = _.intersection(fromUserRoomIds, toUserRoomIds);
    // Find those rooms
    Room.find({id: sharedRoomIds}).exec(...);
  });
});
```

You could make this more elegant using `async.auto`, and don't forget to handle your errors!

Comment: I did that too, but I was hoping for some magic in the ORM. Thanks. (: